# Running QuickCheck against Simple Test w/ Function

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Given the following:

```
test :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Bool
test _ _ = True
```

After compiling the source, I try to run `quickCheck test`:

```
> quickCheck test
<interactive>:27:1:
    No instance for (Show (Int -> Int))
      arising from a use of ‘quickCheck’
    In the expression: quickCheck test
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = quickCheck test
```

Looking at this [Show instance for functions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Show_instance_for_functions), it appears to me that no such instance exists.

How can I run `quickCheck test`, i.e. get around or address the missing `Show` instance for `Int -> Int`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

QuickCheck has a special module [`Test.QuickCheck.Function`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Function.html) for generating "functions" that can be showed (and also "shrinked", which is how QuickCheck simplifies its counterexamples). You can convert them to ordinary functions using `apply`.  For example if you have the file:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Function

test :: Fun Int Int -> Int -> Bool
test _ _ = True

test2 :: Fun Int Int -> Int -> Bool
test2 f x = apply f x == x
```

Then in GHCi:

```
*Main> quickCheck test
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
*Main> quickCheck test2
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 2 tests and 3 shrinks): 
{_->0}
1
```

It *is* actually possible to define a `Show` instance for functions themselves, and use that.  But unless your input type is a finite type like `Bool`, you won't be able to print all information about the function this way.  You can import a dummy instance that shows *no* useful information from `Text.Show.Functions`.

However, the `Test.QuickCheck.Function.Fun` type used above looks like it's been designed to give the essential information much more succinctly, so I'd certainly use that myself if possible.